# Insert Large Json/File System to DB or Compression

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch, logging

I am working with different API and I need to log all of these requests/responds. As of now, I am creating file system for Requests/Responds and it hit more than 1GB per minute. average size of each file is about 7 MB. Since I create file system for logs, I do not have delay for creating them but I have problem with CPU usage.

I do have 2 problems here:

1- creating file system takes lots of storage. I have schedule to compress with Gzip every 5 minutes up to 1000 file.
 2- It looks compression takes lots of CPU usage.

I am looking optimize/faster way to log all these responds.

Thanks,
Soheil

Comment: Do you use logstash? How do you index logs, i hope you dont use the custom mappings, only index what you want search for, store the rest.

Comment: Actually, I am using custom mapping by creating folder and put timestamp on file name. Creating index is not so important for me right now. 

I am looking for a solution to reduce CPU Usage and increase server performance. I am creating 10GB GZip File per day.

Comment: If you let es with default mapping, he will index everything, cost a lots of CPU + disk...

Comment: I think compression take lots of resources since I am not mapping anything. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can you recommend any solution for logging my Request/Responds? Each file size is between 2 MB ~ 7 MB. I need to log each file in millisecond. That's why I am using file system.

Comment: You sould use logstach for sure, it will help you for file management & concurently, could help you for step 1. Can you post your cluster settings parameters ? Is the server isolated? You wont find a magic solution for compression, but please, check back you dont index the whole file, and you only store it in ES...

Comment: Meanwhile I am gathering these data, I would like to check below solution with you.

My friend recommended me below solution:
I just use redis to cache data in Memory and I will put another server for Mongo to collect those data from redis and write it in Mongo with compression. But I am not sure how  much resources it will take or if it good solution for it.

Comment: Use redis to cache big file is not a good idea. It s monothread and he will lock the thread when loading the file, use memcache instead (or take a look to other file caching db). If you only need to index 2 fields, mongo should be better than es for your usage (file size) (as if you should describe it a little more). Plug Redis with a Mongo should solve your cpu issue, but i repeat, is your server isolated? do you need a real time indexation? hadoop hdfs could be a good solution too